# Python Selenium onclick throws ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

On a website I want to interact with using Selenium, there is the following part of the html code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="editToggle('default_name_span', 'edit_name')">
    <img src="img/rename.png?1" alt="change name" title="change name">
</a>
```

This shows a little image that is to be clicked to change the name of an item on that webpage. I tried

```
webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*=edit_name]").click()
```

where `webdriver` is my `selenium.webdriver` instance. Unfortunately, this throws an `ElementNotInteractableException`. I tried a dummy wait of 5 seconds, and also `EC.element_to_be_clickable` and `EC.presence_of_element_located` with `WebDriverWait`.

I tried to click on the `img` instead. This worked without error but didn't produce any (visible) result on the webpage.

Also tried using XPATH:

```
WebDriverWait(webdriver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="default_name_span"]/a')))
WebDriverWait(webdriver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="default_name_span"]/a')))
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="default_name_span"]/a').click();
```

This throws the same exception.

How can I click here? Any ideas?

I didn't find an answer on SO but if there is one and you provide me the link, I'll be happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: Can you please share with us the webpage link? Ty

Comment: It is part of a browser game which cannot be accessed without login data so providing the link without login data is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick^='editToggle']>img[alt='change name'][title='change name']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'editToggle')]/img[@alt='change name' and @title='change name']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This throws `TimeoutException` -- this is why I am asking. How can it be that this element doesn't appear to be clickable though it should be?

Comment: @sampleuser Update the question with the entire error trace log of `ElementNotInteractableException`

Comment: There was a typo in the html I had provided, I fixed this and now your solutions works perfectly well! Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your help :)